# Find limit of $x_n =n2^{-n}, n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

By writing out the first few terms of the sequence, I see that it is a decreasing sequence (monotonic non-increasing) and want to show it converges to 0. But I don't know how to manipulate the expression and I want to find an $N$ and an $\epsilon$ to prove the limit exists formally.

Answer (score 3):

It is well-known that $2^n > n^2$ if $n>4$. This means $\dfrac{1}{2^n} < \dfrac{1}{n^2} \implies \dfrac{n}{2^n} < \dfrac{n}{n^2} = \dfrac{1}{n}$.

Formally, let $\varepsilon >0$, and choose $N$ such that $\dfrac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$. The rest is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Note $\frac{n+1}{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n} \le 2$, so $(n + 1)(1/2)^{n+1} \le n(1/2)^n$, i.e., $x_{n+1} \le x_n$. So $x_n$ decreases. Since $x_n$ is bounded below by $0$, by the monotone convergence theorem, $x_n$ converges to some number $L$. Since $x_{2n} = \frac{2}{n}x_n^2$, taking the limit on both sides results in $L = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

another way : first step , we can prove easily that $ 2^n >n^2 $ for $n>5$ 
so now 
$$0 \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\frac{n}{2^n} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\frac{n}{n^2} \rightarrow 0$$ when $n$ goes to $\infty $ $$\forall \epsilon >0  \space \exists N>n :|\frac{n}{2^n}-0|<\epsilon \\ |\frac{n}{2^n}|<\epsilon \\$$ by knowing  $|\frac{n}{2^n}|<|\frac{n}{n^2}|$ we have
$$\frac{n}{2^n}<\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon \\n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\\N \geq \left \lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon } \right \rfloor+1$$

Answer (score 0):

We would like to show that for every $\phi > 0$ satisfaing $\frac{n}{2^N} < \phi$ there exists $n_0$ that for all $n > n_0$ holds $\frac{n}{2^N} < \phi$. But $\frac{2^n}{n} > \frac{n^2}{n} = n > \frac{1}{\phi}$ so it is sufficient to take $n_0 = \lfloor{\frac{1}{\phi}}\rfloor$.